# How to find the distribution of the result of a compound experiment

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

I'm trying to find the distribution of data collected from a die-roll and coin-toss experiment. The experiment is as follows:

1)Roll a fair die so that you get a number $D \in (1,...,6)$ 
2)Flip a fair coin $D$ number of times (i.e. the value on the dice) and record the number of tails $T$

Repeat this experiment for 10000 runs and define the random variable $W$ as the number of runs needed until an outcome of $T \geq 5$ occurs for the first time.

Am I right in thinking that $T$ would be geometrically or negative binomially distributed? Just a note, I'm doing all my modelling and simulations in R.

Comment: What is the basis for your thinking?

Comment: Because you're trying to find the number of trials before the first success - in this case, a value of $T$ that is greater or equal to 5. I'm just not sure if the previous steps in the experiment would affect anything.

Comment: Well, what do the mechanisms in steps (1) and (2) tell you about the chance that $T\ge 5$?  Do you need to know the details of how this event occurs, or is knowledge of its probability sufficient to answer your question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the last part of your question? Also I'm not sure how to calculate the probability of $T\geq5$ as the number of tosses has the potential to change with each die roll. I know that the roll and the toss would follow a binomial distribution though.

Comment: I think I see what you mean; the condition $D\geq5$ must be met otherwise you couldn't get 5 or more tails.

Comment: You have expressed some doubts ("I'm not just sure") about whether the details of the experiment should play a role in your calculation.  I think that gets to the heart of your question, so I'm trying to direct your attention to that.

Comment: I think I understand, see my comment above.

Comment: I'm still not sure of the distribution though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on the chance of observing five or more tails ($T\ge 5$).  This can happen in two disjoint ways:

- The die shows $5$ (chance is $1/6$) and all five coin flips are tails (chance is $1/2^5=1/32$).
- The die shows $6$ (chance is $1/6$) and five of the six coin flips are tails (chance is $\binom{6}{5}(1/2)^6 = 6/64 = 3/32$.

The total chance is $1/6 \times 1/32 + 1/6 \times 3/32 = 1/6 \times 4/32 = 1/48$.

We have reduced the question to this (or at least I interpret it as such), which clearly you know how to answer:

> An event of interest in an experiment (namely that $T \ge 5$) occurs with probability $1/48$.  The experiment is repeated until this event first occurs.  The number of repetitions needed is recorded as $W$.  What is the distribution of $W$?

By stating the question somewhat abstractly--including only the relevant information--it should now be clear that *how* the experiment is performed is of no consequence and all that matters are two things: (1) that successive runs of the experiment are independent and (2) the probability of the event of interest.

Notice that when attention focuses on $W$, we do not need to know precisely how $T$ is distributed.

---

It is amusing and instructive--although computationally inefficient--to study a simulation built *according to the precise instructions of the experiment.*  I will cheat a little, though: it usually is not needed to run the experiment $10000$ times to compute $W$.  $1000$ times will more than suffice.  This simulation in `R` repeats the entire process $10^4$ times.

```
experiment <- function(n, d=6, p=1/2, t=5) {
  # Returns NA when event `coin >= t` is never observed.  Beware!
  die <- ceiling(runif(n, 0, d)) # Roll a fair die with `d` faces
  coin <- rbinom(n, die, p)      # Flip a coin as many times as shown on the die
  T <- coin >= t                 # Identify when `t` is reached or exceeded
  match(1, T)                    # Count the number of tries needed
}

set.seed(17)
hist(results <- replicate(10^4, experiment(10^3)), probability=TRUE, breaks=40)
lines(dgeom(1:max(results, na.rm=TRUE), 1/48), col="Red", lwd=2) # Is this correct?
```

The code is written to let the die, the tail probability ($1/2$), and the threshold ($5$) easily be varied so that we can study how they influence the results and verify any more general formulas we might care to derive.

[image: Plot]

The red curve plots the PDF of a geometric distribution with parameter $1/48$ for comparison.

Comment: That makes things a lot clearer. I'm a little unsure of the parameters when plotting this in r though. Would it be dgeom(x,1/48)?

Comment: I edited the answer to include a plot in `R`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I can't thank you enough for your trouble!